# Codeigniter Multiple choice quiz app not submitting all the questions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a dynamic multiple choice quiz app in codeigniter. Where admin can add questions and answer options from the backend. The quiz has maximum five questions each page and submits button on the last page. But my problem is when the user clicks the submit button only the last pages answer got submitted and all other pages answer didn't get submitted.

Answer (score -1):

you need to save the answers of last pages is session